# Laravel + Homestead SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No conection possible

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, homestead

I already tried every tipp in this [stackoverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977087/laravel-homestead-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-after-server-move).
But I stil have issues conecting to my MysqlServer on Homestead (based on Vagrant).

I used step by step guide from [Learning Laravel](https://learninglaravel.net/books/laravel/building-a-support-ticket-system)

This is how i start my Homestead and Mysql

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
mysql -u homestead -p
mysql> show Databases
```

(and homestead is showed so the Database exists)

this is my .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

this is my database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Failure log (sorry its partly in german):

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.
 (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)

PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.")

PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead", "homestead", "secret", [])
```

Comment: Can you change your DB_HOST, 127.0.0.1 to localhost ?

Comment: tried that already. also changed env. to localhost. Every combination doesent work. Thats one of the ideas in the linked stackoverflow post :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to use the IP so it's connectible from both remote CLI and your local machine

```
'host' => '192.168.10.10',
```

Comment: I dont realy understand how that works and why i read this nowhere. But this somehow works (???) Thank you after 3+ hours searching you gave me a new answer - that works!!
If you can give me an explanation? - I am no guru at IP's

Comment: You are welcome man!!! You can find it in official documentation!! You just add the "domains" for your sites to the host file on your machine. The hosts file will redirect requests for your Homestead sites into your Homestead machine

Comment: offical Documentation of what? of Homestead?